# Server for web game and android game

Tags: c++, web, web-applications, server

Me and my few colleagues have a project which main goal is to create a game as an web app and android app. Our idea was to create server, which would handle all the logic of the games and store data of the users, so the clients would only show GUI and interact with the player. Unfortunatelly all of us are mainly c++ programmers and we only have experience in writing simple desktop apps.

And because of that we wanted to do it in such way, that we could easily implement multithreaded server with Qt library, that would catch messages from clients, parse them, pass them to logic, and then respond to client. It would be similiar with clients, as they would need to catch servers messages and react to them as well as they would need to send messages to server with users requests.

Android client would be implemented in java of course, but most of the our hesitations regards web client.

We would be very grateful for your opinions and advices on this matter. What lanugages and frameworks should we use to make it work. Also I'd like to mention that we would like to implement server in c++, because we would like to learn how servers work on lower levels.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is way too broad and leaves much place to opinion only answer...  Of course Qt + C++ allows for nice portable UI on any desktop with easy network access. You could also think about using a dedicated protocol or stick to HTTP. The latter passes through any firewall and has nice client libraries on Android but is not connected and requires the *HTTP session* horror. Another key design decision is the number of concurrent clients (single or multi-server, bottlenecks, etc.) and the choice statefull vs stateless

Comment: Even were your question more narrownly specified, asking for language and framework recommendations would also be grounds for rejection; stack overflow is really for dealing with _specific problems_. You'd probably be best off searching for a decicated game development forum and asking there.

Comment: Thank You for your answers and suggestions. I just wanted to ask whether doing two separate servers, one for webapp, and second for game logic and users database makes sense? So the server webapp would connect to game logic server, similar android app would connect to the logic server and react accordingly to servers commands. Also all clients would almost have no logic, all logic would be done in app logic server.

Comment: @Michal: you should stick to the layered pattern. One layer is UI with an android app, a web application and/or heavy C++-Qt client, the logic lies in another layer. That way only thin interfaces will change if you use one single server or two servers.